# How to centre a html5 section element? verticaly

Tags: html, css, centering

here is basically my html structure the content section is the part which i want centred between the header and footer so that on all resolutions its in the middle. I have tried using the table method where you put a div around the section with display:table and then set the content section as display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; but it seems to affect the positioning of divs/sections within the content and positions the section top left of the screen ontop of the header element which has position:absolute;.

```
<header>
</header>
<section id="container">
<section id="content">
</section>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: To give you an example of why copying and pasting isn't helpful, I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y47Fd/) of your code. It's a helpful site to troubleshoot from. If you decide to give us a link to a jsfiddle you create, make sure to still put your code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume this:

```
div {width: 300px; height: 200px;}
```

you can add:

```
div {position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;}
```

It's good practice to put a "wrap" around all elements inside of the body tag.

Let me know how that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

For first column;

```
float: left;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
```

for second and so on;

```
float: left;
position: absolute;
left: 70%;
```

But this approach is inefficient, you may wish to use just `float:left;` inside divs.